# how to change character code while input(converting an ascii code to unicode) for windows phone?

Tags: c#, unicode, windows-phone-8, character, ascii

I want to change a value of ASCII code of a character to Unicode value. I mean I want to replace the value with a Unicode value.

If I enter 'A' it will be converted and the will appear as "আ" (a Bengali character).

Is there any suggestion how may I do this.

I want to do it in c# for windows8 mobile development as a purpose of developing a keyboard for windows 8 mobile phone.

All your suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to achieve - any ASCII value *is* the Unicode value for the same character.

Comment: If I enter 'A' it will be converted and the will appear as "আ" (a Bengali character). now its clear I think..thanks for your comments

Comment: Not clear enough, where do you enter 'A' and where is the output as "আ", do you have some code?

Comment: No, it's *very* far from clear. Why would it be converted to that? What rules are you trying to implement?

Comment: oh sorry. In windows 8 mobile keyboard. I am trying to work on keyboard software form windows mobile